# Magento 2 + media query syntax

Tags: magento2, less, less-css

I have found there is syntax for desktop devices is

> .media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break =
>   @screen__m) {  }

But i need media query for 768px to 1240px desktop version only. Any one have idea about min & max condition for that media query.

Comment: Please check your custom theme "_variable.less" file there you will get exact idea about syntax with this variable used in that.

Comment: I know about variables, i need syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below code in your less file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1240) { width: 75%; //your css goes here}
```